# How `angular2` exports a component?

Tags: angular

I am creating a component like this: ( from the sample )

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1> ~ My First Angular 2-0 App By Gulp Automation ~ </h1>'
})

export class AppComponent { } //what it is exporting here?
```

and importing to another module:

```ts
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component' //what it's imports here

bootstrap(AppComponent); //it works.
```

in index.html :

```ts
<script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register', //what is means?
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

I am not able to understand the logic behind, any one help me please?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that these links could help you: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart and https://daveceddia.com/angular-2-dependencies-overview/.

In fact, SystemJS is responsible to implement the module logic and the link between them. That's why you need to include the SystemJS file (`systemjs`) in your HTML page and configure it using `System.config` and finally load the main component of your Angular2 application with `System.import`.

You explicitly use SystemJs at startup `System.import`. In other elements of your application, the tool is used implicitly especially if you use TypeScript. In this case, a simple `import` is enough to import another module. If you have a look at transpiled files (JavaScript files), you will see that SystemJS is used.

The appendix **SystemJS Configuration** (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#systemjs) could give you some hints about the configuration of SystemJS for an Angular2 application

Here is the link to the documentation regarding module formats (the `format` attribute in the `System.config` block): https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md. By using the `register` value for the `format` attribute, you specify System.register is used to define modules.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 2):

> export class AppComponent { } //what it is exporting here?

This is explained (briefly) in the [Architecture Overview](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#module) guide:

> `export class AppComponent { }`
>
> The export statement tells TypeScript that this is a module whose AppComponent class is public and accessible to other modules of the application.
>
> When we need a reference to the AppComponent, we import it like this:
>
> `import {AppComponent} from './app.component';`
>
> The import statement tells the system it can get an AppComponent from a module named app.component located in a neighboring file. The module name (AKA module id) is often the same as the filename without its extension.

Comment: @Component decorator identifies the class immediately below it as a component, and provides the template and related component-specific metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Component like a module which is packing some code inside, and other module to use when u export this "module"

```
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
```

AppComponent is the name of the class, angular2 know the component name "AppComponent" that served, './app.component' means "same directory and find the file named "app.component.ts"

I am new to ng2, hope it can help u

Comment: so, `import` takes whole file instead of the class. is it?

Comment: import "module name" from "library" makes sense if you've learned oop language like python,
"library" maybe angular library like "angular2/core"../common.. etc, otherwise, u may be import local module like "app.component" with ../, ../../, ./ this pattern